# Applying texture shows some weird artifacts

Tags: texturing

I'm getting these weird spots on my model when they don't exist in my texture. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Which spots are you asking about? There is a circle and 2 lines on the texture above. And a circle and 2 lines mapped on the mesh. What is not as expected?

Comment: Those lines are straight on my texture but when you look at it bigger on the ship they look pixelated. @MrZak

Comment: Pixelization is visible on the circle itself as well and is related to resolution of the image compared to size of the drawing. To hide that you can change falloff settings of the brush to make it hard in the middle and smooth on the margins.

Comment: Thanks I'll change some settings. Do you want to turn that into an answer?

Comment: Answer with details about what worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These artifacts were caused by not having a big enough texture size for my texture. Once I made it a 4k image the issue was fixed.

[image]